# Avoid inspect element to make the read only or disable Text Box to enable and writable

Tags: asp.net

In given my Text Box is read only and enable false, but what the issue is i can able to change Text Box Read only to writable and enable true when inspect element in browser. how to solve the issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent this as this is a browser feature,all you can do is apply some server-side logic.(hint:you can try to keep track in session or cookies).